# Run a binary from Node.JS and relay the behavior exactly on the console, including prompts

Tags: node.js, command-line, child-process

I'm making a cli tool with Node.JS. I run another binary file from within node, and the other process asks for a password at some point.

So what I need is to simply launch the other process, and put it "in charge" of the terminal, so the other process handles the prompts and the console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'inherit'` for the [stdio option](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio) of [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options):

```
const spawn = require( 'child_process' ).spawn;
spawn( '/path/to/binary', [], { stdio: 'inherit' } );
```