# Why async/await exec doesn't output stdout

Tags: node.js

I'm struggling to use async/await while outputing the results as they go to the terminal (windows).
I don't want to put the results into a variable and `console.log` it, but to display the stdout normally (as if the command was put to a terminal).

This is the failed attempt:

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');
    const {promisify} = require('util');
    const exec_async = promisify(exec);

        async function start() {
        var result = await exec_async('echo "hi" &&  sleep 3 && echo "hi2"');

        console.log(result.stdout) // only prints final results, and not what's between!

        }

start().then(/*() => console.log('Done!')*/)
```

Would love some advice on that! thanks

Comment: Is this helpful at all? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49737520/772035

Comment: Your `exec()` process has it's own stdout.  If you want that to go to your stdout, then you would have to stream it there.

Comment: If you only want stdout to inherit you can do this: `stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'ignore']`, although you would likely want `['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit']` so the stderr is inherited too.

Comment: @SteveK - That's not the issue.  All `async` functions return a promise automatically.

Comment: @Paulpro - Any way this will work with "exec"?

Comment: @jfriend00 - I edited the code example to emphasize the question --> how can I print the live results as they go? how do i "stream" it?

Comment: The only difference between exec and spawn is that exec buffers outout, whereas spawn streams it. If you want to stream output, use spawn.

Comment: Oh ! nice to know! any chance you provide an example around the code I've mentioned? I fail to implement this

Comment: The promisify won't really work, you'll need to listen for the `exit` event instead and then you could resolve a Promise if you want. You'll also need the option `shell: true` since it looks like you want to run a few commands in a shell and not a single command directly.

Comment: Could you help with a code example? I fail to understand :(

Comment: `require('child_process').spawn( 'echo "hi" &&  sleep 3 && echo "hi2"', [ ], { shell: true,  stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'] } );`